# bison -d create head file can't include head file correctly

Tags: c, bison

just sample the case

test.grm

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%token id
%start program

%%    
program:   exp    
exp:   ID    
ID: id
```

bison -d test.grm -o test.c aute generate the test.h

```
#ifndef YY_TEST_H
# define YY_TEST_H
#ifndef YYDEBUG
# define YYDEBUG 0
#endif
#if YYDEBUG
extern int yydebug;
#endif

#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
   enum yytokentype {
     id = 258
   };
#endif

#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef int YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define yystype YYSTYPE /* obsolescent; will be withdrawn */
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
#endif
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
#ifdef YYPARSE_PARAM
#if defined __STDC__ || defined __cplusplus
int yyparse (void *YYPARSE_PARAM);
#else
int yyparse ();
#endif
#else /* ! YYPARSE_PARAM */
#if defined __STDC__ || defined __cplusplus
int yyparse (void);
#else
int yyparse ();
#endif
#endif /* ! YYPARSE_PARAM */
#endif /* !YY_TEST_H  */
```

you can see #include  was not in this file.This will have a problem when the .grm use some defines that was defined in the head file in   %{   %}.

here is my question, how can i auto generate the test.h include what included in %{  %}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated header `test.h` contains none of your code, but just the parser API; so there's no issue there: There won't be code that needs code between `{%` and `%}`.

The generated C file contains both your code between `{%` and `%}` and your action code (together with the generated parser logic of course).  So again no issue either.

If you want a header file that contains both the generated parser API plus your own API, you'll have to do the `#include`-ing the other way around: Include the generated `test.h` in your own header file.